# How to display a particular drive, when the open dialogs not find the previously selected path?

Tags: vb6

USING VB 6

My code.

```
CommonDialog1.DialogTitle = "Open File"
CommonDialog1.Filter = "Database (1.mdb) |1.mdb"
CommonDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
CommonDialog1.Flags = cdlOFNFileMustExist + cdlOFNHideReadOnly
CommonDialog1.CancelError = True
On Error Resume Next
CommonDialog1.ShowOpen
If Err Then
    MsgBox "Select Database"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I am using open dialog in my project. When I run the project I selected the file from the remote system.

Suppose if the remote system was not available, Next time when I select the open dialog, the open dialog should display the c Drive

Now it is displaying my Project folder, it should display the c Drive

How to write a code for this condition?

Need VB6 code Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve what you are asking:

To get `FileSystemObject`, you must add a reference in your project to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'.

```
Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
Dim currentDir As String
currentDir = fs.GetParentFolderName(CommonDialog1.FileName)
If fs.FolderExists(currentDir) Then
    CommonDialog1.InitDir = currentDir
Else
    CommonDialog1.FileName = ""
    CommonDialog1.InitDir = "C:\"
End If
```

**EDIT:**
 You must also set CommonDialog1.FileName = ""

Answer (score -1):

The answer your looking for is on the [VBCity site](http://vbcity.com/forums/faq.asp?fid=9&cat=Common+Dialog&#TID82667)
The Code example there allows you to do exactly what your asking for.